# Laravel multiple controller functions one route

Tags: php, laravel

What I'm trying to achieve is post all news by @foreach and between the @foreach do another @foreach to post all comments with the ID from the news post.

I'm unsure on how to pass this ID, to the getNewsComments function.

My controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use App\News;
use App\newsComments;


class newsController extends Controller
{
    public function getAllNews(){
        $results = News::all();
        return view('index')->with('news', $results);
    }
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/', 'newsController@getAllNews');
```

News model:

```
class News extends Model
{
    // set table
    protected $table = 'lg_news';


    public function newsComments(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\newsCommments');
    }
}
```

Comment model:

```
class newsComments extends Model
{
    // set table name
    protected $table = 'lg_newscomments';

}
```

view

```
@foreach ($news as $article)

  @foreach($news->$newsComments as $comment)
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Error:

> Undefined variable: newsComments (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\resources\views\index.blade.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
return view('index')->with('news', $results);
```

to

```
return view('index', ['news' => $results]);
```

and it probably will work.

PS: `with()` function will set a session! It will not pass a variable to view.

Comment: Getting the same error: Undefined variable: newsComments (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\resources\views\index.blade.php)

Comment: change that method name to comments (because we are referring to that with $post->comments in the view page) and it will work

Comment: You mean this bit?  @foreach($news->$newsComments as $comment) - if I change it to  @foreach($news->$comments as $comment) it gives me the same error, but with comments.

Comment: remove the $ sign before the the comments! It needs to be @foreach($news->comments as $comment)

Reminder: And be sure to rename the method name at News model to comments instead of newsComments

That will fix your issues

Comment: Property [comments] does not exist on this collection instance. I've removed the $ and changed the method to public function comments()

Comment: It needs to be @foreach($article->comments as $comment) in your case - because you are accessing comments for every single article

Comment: Ahh.... Ofcourse, but it still gives me an error: Class 'App\newsCommments' not found. Probably to do with return $this->hasMany('App\newsCommments');?

Comment: You are welcome man! Don't forget to vote up all my answers if they helped you :)

Comment: I've got one more question though: How does it actually know which Comments are part of the articles? In my DB for comments I've got news_id table, does it automatically detect this? I'm confused on this.

Comment: You have linked them (ie created a relation between two tables News and Comments) with this line return $this->hasMany('App\newsCommments'); in the News model

Comment: Alright, so it looks at the row news_id in my comments table? so if I'd change that to example_id it won't work?

Comment: You can rename the field ID in whatever you want! Whatever name you add to the news table it needs to be the same as a reference key in the comments table. Did you got it?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need multiple routes you just need to have two tables related to each other with 1:N relationship

Article (1) -> Comments (N)

Then you will create a model for each table and create the relation like explained in the Laravel documentation

[One to Many relationship in Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

Then you will fetch all posts and pass them to the view:

```
public function getAllArticles()
{
 $posts = Post::all();
 return view('view-name', $posts);
}
```

And at the end, create a view and show posts and comments:

```
    @foreach($posts as $post)
     {{ $post->title }}
     {{ $post->body }}
     @foreach($post->comments as $comment)
      {{ $comment->title }}
      {{ $comment->body }}
     @endforeach
    @endforeach
```

Reminder: `$post->comments` , **comments** is the method name defined in the model where you create the relationship

Define route at web.php:

```
Route::get('/', 'ControllerName@getAllArticles');
```

Go to `localhost:8000/` (or to your site domain if the site is hosted) to see the result

Comment: I've been messing around with it, but I don't get it to work.
A question: 
Route::get('/post/{id}', 'ControllerName@methodName')->name('route-name'); Does this route only get posts if you visit the url /post/'id'? Because I need it on my index page, and not on a seperate page.

Comment: ControllerName is your controller where you have defined the method and methodName is the method name itself. If for example your controller is called ArticleController and the method inside that controller is called getArticleById you have to define the route like this Route::get('/article/{id}', 'ArticleController@getArticleById'); 

And URL address is localhost:8000/article/1 (will show the post with id equal to 1)

Comment: Yes, I got that. But doing /article/{id} doesn't this mean you'll actually have to 'visit' www.website.com/article/23 (for example)?

What I would like to achieve, is to have the News on the index page + comments aswel.

Comment: Yes exactly! See the answer I just edited :) and mark it as correct if it helped you solve the problem. Best of luck

Comment: What I would like to achieve, is to have the News on the index page + comments aswel, without having to navigate to www.website.com/article/1. So it's just www.website.com where News is shown + Comments of the news, sorry if I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Check out the answer, I just adapted to your needs.

Comment: I'm still stuck.. I've modified my question with my modified bit of code. I think I'm not linking the two tables correct.